# How can I erase my objects without Background Image?

Tags: java, android, paint

I want to erase my bitmap but I don't want to erase background image. When I try to erase is white and it draw very hard in frames.

This is from **CanvasView**

```
erasePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
//erasePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

erasePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
erasePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
erasePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
erasePaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

//....

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setPathEffect(null);


    if(bitmap!=null){

        for(MyEraser e:eraserList){
            canvas.drawPath(e.p,erasePaint);
            invalidate();
        }

        final OnTouchListener eraseListener = new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                //  erasePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                //FirstActivity.ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        myEraser = new MyEraser();
                        lastTouchX = event.getX();
                        lastTouchY = event.getY();
                        myEraser.mouseDown(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        resetDirtyRect(event.getX(),event.getY());
                        int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                        for(int i=0;i<historySize;i++){
                            float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                            float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                            expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);

                            myEraser.mouseUp(historicalX, historicalY);
                        }
                        myEraser.mouseUp(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        eraserList.add(myEraser);
                        break;

                    default:
                        Log.d("mock it up", "Unknown touch event  " + event.toString());
                        return false;
                }

                invalidate(
                    (int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

                lastTouchX = event.getX();
                lastTouchY = event.getY();
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is **MyEraser**

```
public class MyEraser {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Path p = new Path();

    public MyEraser(){
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }

    public void mouseDown(float x, float y) {
        //path.addCircle(x,y,5,Path.Direction.CW);
        p.moveTo( x, y );
        // path.lineTo(x, y);
    }

    public void mouseMove(Path path, float x, float y) {
        // path.addCircle(x,y,5,Path.Direction.CW);
    }

    public void mouseUp(float x, float y){
        //path.addCircle(x,y,5,Path.Direction.CW);
        p.lineTo(x, y);
    }

    public void draw(Canvas c,Path path){
        //paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(7);
        c.drawPath(p, paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Started over for better explanation :)

I am not familiar with Android, in fact I have never used it. Use this code as an example of how to organize your code, rather than a functional code.

```
class MyView extends View {
    private Eraser myEraser;
    private Bitmap myBackgroundImage;
    private Canvas myForegroundCanvas;

    public MyView(Context context, Attributes, attrs) {
        myEraser = new Eraser()
        myBackgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_background_name);
        Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // the width and height of the view
        myForegroundCanvas = new Canvas(image);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // update your eraser path
        return true;
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);

        //for (Eraser item : eraserList) {
            // if you have multiple eraser, add them to a list
            myEraser.draw(myForegroundCanvas);
        //}

        canvas.drawCanvas(myForegroundCanvas, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

The main idea is to keep the separation between your background and foreground images. That way, you could easily change the background and it would be updated. You could also have a reset on the foreground to erase everything, etc.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm beginner in android and java

Comment: I will try to find a link that explain my thoughts. :)

Comment: I tried to rework my answer. Let me know if you need more explanations.

Comment: well my Background is an Image imported from my gallery

Comment: There is no method drawCanvas on Canvas.